# Не выравнивается кнопка по вертикали LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml

Имеется часть разметки:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/upperLayout"
        android:layout_above="@id/button2">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="@string/default_text"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/text_like_button"
                tools:ignore="NestedWeights" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

В нем есть проблема: кнопка, почему-то не выравнивается по центру по вертикали, хотя android:gravity="center_vertical". 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем проблема?

Comment: я вам порекомендую воспользоватся ConstraintLayout вместо LinearLayout. Во первых он быстрее в работе, во вторых в вёрстке интерфейса, в третьих  влаживать LinearLayout в LinearLayout не есть хорошо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:gravity` отвечает за выравнивание ТЕКСТА внутри кнопки.

Используйте `android:layout_gravity` - это "внешняя" гравитация самой кнопки.

И небольшое замечание не по сути: если вы ставите вес (для `LinearLayout`), то `height/width` (в зависимости от ориентации родителя) лучше ставить = `0dp`

Comment: не "лучше ставить", а надо ставить